# How to trigger scrolltop in vue 2 single page application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have used vee-validate for form validation in vue2 application. On click location button I need to scrolltop to the error message.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success"  style="border-radius: 4px" @click.prevent="addNewLocation"> location
     <span class="ti-plus"></span>
</a>
```

Here **addNewLocation()** method action is:

```
addNewLocation () {
                this.$validator.validateAll().then(isValid => {
                    if (isValid) {
                        this.$store.commit('order/MUTATE_ADD_NEW_LOCATION', {stair_built_location: this.stair_built_location});
                        let locationArrayIndex = this.order.locations.length - 1;
                        this.$router.push({ name: 'StairHeader', params: { location_index: locationArrayIndex }});
                    } else {
                        window.scrollTo(0,0);
                        console.log('invalid');
                    }
                });
            },
```

In code **window.scrollTo(0,0)** does not work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error here, `window.scrollTo(0,0)` is a standard on almost all browsers and still works here.

Comment: This is not working bro. Normally it should work for any event. It is used in a component. and when the code run vue2  makes the code minified. I think it cant make sense in the minified js.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `scrollBehavior` within your routing add function like this

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
     if (to.hash) {
         return { selector: to.hash } 
     } 
  }
```

It should detect if any #something was added in URL and scroll to it.

You can use it with for example router link then pass `hash` in `to="`

```
<router-link :to=" { hash: #IDofDiv } "> scroll to div </router-link>
```

you should also be able to just add hash from code. You can find more, complex info in [vuejs router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html).

Remember to add div with this ID.

Comment: Actually this works for changing route. But here it needed to work in same route and same component. I need to scrolltop automatically if there are error message in input forms to show the validation error message, clicking on submit button.

Comment: Show me your routing pls you can upload to github gist and share link to not make mess in question

Comment: You added this function after closing routes?

Comment: Here is no routing issue.The code is given on the top, I need to scroll page on a button event. On click a button the page should scrolltop. If it is done then I can solve my problem.

Comment: Look i gave you solution of how you should accomplish it. It should work. I gave code which is tested and was working in many of my projects. I added code which you should place in router so I would like to see if you paste it in correct place. Additionally you can take a look at docs which are showing exactly how to do what you want.